# Why is the newton quotient equal to zero here if it is $0/0$?

Tags: calculus

This book states that if $g(x+h)-g(x)=0$, then the newton quotient $(g(x+h)-g(x))/h$ is equal to zero. The context is that the author is trying to prove the chain rule: the proof is attached below.
I am also not sure why at the bottom, $f'(g(x))g'(x)$ is set to zero because of this fact. I would appreciate if someone could explain why these things are set to zero.

[image]

Comment: Hi there, could you provide further context, for the image, because $g'(x)$ is not always zero. But it may be possible that this maybe a derivation for some theorem such as Rolle' s Theorem,etc.

Comment: It seems that you didn't provide the beginning of the proof. It is likely that the proof starts by defining $h$ as a *nonzero* number.

Comment: Also, from which book did you take this proof?

Comment: The book is Lang's calculus. If g(x+h)-g(x)=0, does this not mean h is equal to zero though?

Comment: In fact, it does not mean that.

Answer (score 3):

When we write $h \rightarrow 0$ in a limit, we mean that $h$ is close to $0$, but is not $0$. Therefore, if $h$ is in $H_2$, then $g(x+h) - g(x) = 0$, so $$\dfrac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{h} = \dfrac{0}{h} = 0$$ for all $h \in H_2$, $h \ne 0$. The thing is that it is not a $0/0$ limit. While the denominator approaches zero, the numerator does something stronger than approaching zero. It **is** zero.

Comment: This is a nice answer but I am confused by the two last lines: are you claiming that a constant function $f(x)=0$ does not approach $0$ when $x$ approaches $a=0$ (or any $a$)?

Comment: Well, you are correct, i wrote it in a confusing way indeed. I've edited my answer.

Comment: thanks, I understand that the limit is equal to zero. Why is the newton quotient (not the limit) said to be '0 for such values'?

Comment: Because the numerator in the Newton quotient is equal to zero, whereas the denominator is not necessarily zero. For $h=0$ it is not defined, but for every other value in $H_2$, the Newton quotient equals zero.

Comment: why is it the case that if g(x+h)-g(x) =0, h is not 0? Is the function g assumed to be non pure and has a different output for same input?

Comment: For example, take $g(x) = x^2$. If $x = -1$ and $h = 2$, then $g(x) = g(1) = 1$, $g(x+h) = g(-1+2) = g(1) = 1$ as well, but $-1 \neq 1$.

Comment: I see, thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142044/discussion-between-god-and-gondim).

Answer (score 0):

I think it talks about a function g continuous at $x_0$, and a function f also continuous but around $x_1=g(x_0)$

It says that in these conditions, if $x_0$ was a local extreme (min or max) for g, then $g(x_0)$ becomes a local extreme for f.

This is useful when plotting quadratics or trig functions for example.

To prove it uses a set of values around $x_0$ where $g(x_0+h)=g(x_0)$ rendering $f(g(x_0+h)=f(x_0)$ therefore the slope of the tangent of f must be zero, or the set of remaining values around $x_0$ which renders $f\prime(g(x_0))=0$ because $g\prime(x_0)=0$ is a given.

I guess that your concern is related to $g(x_0+h)=g(x_0)$, because if $x_0$ was a local extreme you would expect something of the kind $g(x_0-h_1)=g(x_0+h_2)$